# How can I pass parameter class name in generic constructor

Tags: java, spring

```
public class RestResponseDTO<T extends Object> {
    private  T result;
}
```

code where I am initializing this:

```
public RestResponseDTO getObject(String url,Class clz){
    Class cv = clz.getClass();
    RestResponseDTO<cv> restResponseDTO =restTemplate.getForObject(url,RestResponseDTO.class);
    return restResponseDTO;
}
```

How can I initalize `RestResponseDTO` in my `getObject` function depending upon the `clz` type?

ps- getForObject is spring restTemplate's standard function- http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html#getForObject-java.lang.String-java.lang.Class-java.lang.Object...-

Comment: `clz.getClass() == Class.class`

Comment: Class cv = new Class();

Comment: what do you want to achieve here? Your return type is anyway raw type.

Comment: @hedgehog nice joke... the constructor of `java.lang.Class` is private and it requires a parameter.

Comment: @fabian obviously what i wrote was a comment not a well structured answer, i just gave a hint of what he asked, if its not what eh expected then he should have made the question in a more clarifying way....

Answer (score 0):

You can add method like this:

```
void init(Class clazz) {
     //you initializing logic
}
```

and call it

```
RestResponseDTO<cv> restResponseDTO =restTemplate.getForObject(url,RestResponseDTO.class);
restResponseDTO.init(clz);
return restResponseDTO;
```

PS: Your `cv` variable will always have same value.

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

ResponseEntity responseEntity  = restTemplate.getForObject(url,RestResponseDTO.class);

and 
responseEntity.getBody() 
will give you Object T.

Answer (score 0):

You can not pass a class with generic parameter to a method that has the parametertype `Class<?>`, you need something like `Type`.

One way (the only i am aware of) around is: create a concrete type that includes the generic parameter.

```
class IntegerResponse extends RestResponse<Integer>{
    ...
}
```

That way you can pass `IntegerResponse.class`